# Getting undesirable output while using text file in function to replace a word

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I am fairly new to filing in C++ and I am trying to build a program which takes the input from the user for the text file, asks the user which word he/she wants to replace and displays the text file after replacing the word. Program shows no errors but fails to achieve the desirable output.
[image]

```
#include<fstream.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


void getdata(){
  char s[80];
  int n;

    cout<<"How many lines would you like to enter\n";
    cin>>n;cout<<"Please go ahead\n"<<endl;

  ofstream f1("story.txt");

    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
    cin.getline(s,80);
    f1<<s;
     }
        f1.close();
 }


  void showdata(fstream& f1){
 char s[80];

  f1.open("story.txt",ios::in);

    while(!f1.eof()){
     f1>>s;
     cout<<s<<" ";
     }
        f1.close();
 }



void main(){
 char s[20], replace[20];
 getdata();
  cout<<endl<<"which word do you want to replace\n";
  cin>>s;
    cout<<endl<<"what do you want to replace it with?\n";
    cin>>replace;


     fstream f1("Story.txt",ios::in);
     fstream f2("temp.txt",ios::out);

     char word[20];

      while(!f1.eof()){
        f1>>word;
         if(strcmp(word,s))
         strcpy(word,replace);
        f2<<word;
      }

         f1.close();
         f2.close();
         showdata(f2);
          remove("story.txt");
          rename("temp.txt","story.txt");


 }
```

Comment: TurboC++? Please tell your teacher to update the course with at least 20 years

Comment: yes sorry! the word does not get replaced. just added the output screen as well above

Comment: Side note about `while(!f1.eof())`:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons

Comment: @Rockboy987 That's all not remotely valid c++ code. Use a more modern compiler, get familiar with `std::string` and how to use `std::transform()`.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two problems with your code (aside from the obvious problem of using Turbo C++):

1. `strcmp` returns *falsy* value when strings are equal.

Your `if` condition should look like this:

```
     if(strcmp(word,s) == 0)
```

2. You output data from different text file than you wrote to

If you'd open `story.txt` in your favourite text editor after execution of your program, you'd (probably) notice it looks like this:

```
apple banana banana banana banana banana banana
```

This is due to point 1., but notice that the file *actually changed*. The thing is, you open `story.txt` for reading again **before** it was renamed from `temp.txt`, so when you output it to the screen, it still has the old content (and `temp.txt` has the new stuff)